# Python: Ctrl+Click for buttons (capture invocation event)

Tags: python, scripting

Is it possible to get if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed when I click on my python button?

I would like make different behaviors for my button operator.

Example:
<kbd>LMB</kbd> - Select some objects
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> - Deselect some objects

I don't use a modal operator / the `modal()` method. I've been making a simple script.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if you use an `invoke()` method in your operator instead of `execute()`, because there's a 3rd parameter given to invoke - an **event object**.

That object has attributes about modifier key states among a [few other pieces of input info](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73a_release/bpy.types.Event.html).

Here's an example script, that adds a button to the 3D View. You can hold e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> down and click on it to let the operator report `Ctrl+Alt+Click` in the info area:

```
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        ev = []
        if event.ctrl:
            ev.append("Ctrl")
        if event.shift:
            ev.append("Shift")
        if event.alt:
            ev.append("Alt")
        if event.oskey:
            ev.append("OS")
        ev.append("Click")

        self.report({'INFO'}, "+".join(ev))
        return {'FINISHED'}


def draw_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.prepend(draw_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.remove(draw_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Note that there can also be an `execute()` method in the operator, but it won't be called unless the execution context is not `INVOKE_*`, but `EXEC_*`. The default behavior of the Python Console is, for instance, to execute an operator, not to invoke it.

If there's no `execute()` and you run `bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()` in the console, an error will be reported in the System Console and the operator abort with `{'PASS_THROUGH'}`. You can explicitly invoke it however: `bpy.ops.object.simple_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')`

Comment: As always you save me. You are my hero!

Comment: You're welcome. On a side note: It's not possible to let the button change (label or icon) based on the held down modifier keys. Actually it is, but only if you monitor their state continuously - which would require a modal operator running in the background all the time. Plus, you would need to `tag_redraw()` the region. See my prototype over here: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?326991-Transform-Orientations-typical-interaction-use-case-%28workflow-UI%29

Comment: great answer, you made a touched on few points here that I tripped over for a while before I figured it out.

Comment: @CoDEmanX I've been looking for a solution to a recent problem I encountered. For my problem, I need to click on a node in the node editor to trigger LBM clicking so that the values of the 'Image Node` block get updated. I think a version of your solution will provide me what I want but I do not know how I can adapt your answer. Could you take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102790/how-to-activate-trigger-lmb-click-events-a-specific-view-node-to-update-conten) and let me know if you think I am doing something wrong?